# Json-cpp - how to initialize from string and get string value?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

My code below crashes(Debug Error! R6010 abort() has been called). Can you help me? I'd also would like to know how to initialize the json object from a string value.

```
Json::Value obj;
obj["test"] = 5;
obj["testsd"] = 655;
string c = obj.asString();
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hello it is pretty simple:

1 - You need a CPP JSON value object (Json::Value) to store your data

2 - Use a Json Reader (Json::Reader) to read a JSON String and parse into a JSON Object

3 - Do your Stuff :)

Here is a simple code to make those steps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/reader.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/writer.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{

    std::string strJson = "{\"mykey\" : \"myvalue\"}"; // need escape the quotes

    Json::Value root;   
    Json::Reader reader;
    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( strJson.c_str(), root );     //parse process
    if ( !parsingSuccessful )
    {
        std::cout  << "Failed to parse"
               << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages();
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << root.get("mykey", "A Default Value if not exists" ).asString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile: g++ YourMainFile.cpp -o main -l jsoncpp

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Wow, this has been the best quick primer on C++ and json I have seen.

awesome

Comment: Thanks, love saving time.

Comment: With raw string (C++11), you may use `strJson = R"({"mykey" : "myvalue"})";`.

Comment: FWIW, you should only need to include the single `json.h` header.

Comment: Json::Reader is deprecated.  Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead.

Answer (score 27):

[`Json::Reader` is deprecated.](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/deprecated.html) Use [`Json::CharReader`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_char_reader.html) and [`Json::CharReaderBuilder`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_char_reader_builder.html) instead:

```
std::string strJson = R"({"foo": "bar"})";

Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
Json::CharReader* reader = builder.newCharReader();

Json::Value json;
std::string errors;

bool parsingSuccessful = reader->parse(
    strJson.c_str(),
    strJson.c_str() + strJson.size(),
    &json,
    &errors
);
delete reader;

if (!parsingSuccessful) {
    std::cout << "Failed to parse the JSON, errors:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << errors << std::endl;
    return;
}

std::cout << json.get("foo", "default value").asString() << std::endl;
```

Kudos to p-a-o-l-o for their answer here: [Parsing JSON string with jsoncpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283908/parsing-json-string-with-jsoncpp/47284656)

Comment: Thanks for this update.  It never ceases to amaze me how simple code gets deprecated and replaced by 3x complexity..  Cheers.

Comment: Documentation link is broken; now at:  http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using Json::CharReader and Json::CharReaderBuilder by using stringstream instead.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "jsoncpp/json/json.h"
    
int main() {
        std::string strJson = "{\"mykey\" : \"myvalue\"}"; 
        Json::Value obj;
    
        // read a JSON String
        stringstream(strJson) >> obj;
    
        // get string value
        std::string value1 = obj["mykey"].asString();

        // or to get a default value if it isn't set
        std::string value2 = obj.get("mykey", "...").asString();
        return 0;
}
```