# Access specific fields in json file (C++)

Tags: c++, json, ifstream

```
char c;
std::cout<<"Hello World";
std::ifstream people_file("query.json");
while(people_file.get(c)){
    std::cout<<c;
}
```

This is my code, tho I am able to print whole json file. But I don't know how to access specific columns in it.
Under given is a snapshot of the .json file.[Suppose I want to access "_id" and "duration" fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGniV.jpg)

Comment: Are you using MongoDB

Comment: FYI: that isn't a proper JSON formatted file. Anyway, you need to _parse_ it.

Comment: Try to use a JSON parsing library instead of doing it all yourself. Parsing and handling JSON is far from trivial, and there are already libraries which will handle all the tricky bits for you.

Comment: @AkshayRohilla yes, MongoDB

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have exported this file from mongo, haven't made any changes in it. So, it should be a json file.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121378/json-cpp-how-to-initialize-from-string-and-get-string-value

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just guide me, how to do it. I am new to using json with C++

Comment: @Lieutenant.X no. It is a MongoDB formatted file. A standard JSON parser will fail to parse it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have to use this file for my work, any suggestions. How my problem can be solved if other stuffs can be used?

Comment: You need to have Mongo output something else or you need to transform it. For example you can quote all of the non-JSON values like changing `NumberInt(18)` to `"NumberInt(18)"`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I can even use csv, tell me which file would be easy to read and parse in C++