# how to concat integer and wstring and put them in a static char array

Tags: c++

newbie to c++,

Currently, I have a hard coded json stored in a char array

```
static CHAR data[]= "{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"test\"}";
```

I want to make the `values` in the json coming from `dynamic values`

for instance

```
int id = 1;

std::wstring name = "joe";
```

May I ask how can I achieve that,thanks

Comment: I'd use a JSON library to create and manipulate JSON values. The nlohmann one is really easy to use. Not sure how well it supports wide strings, though; you might have to convert to utf-8 yourself first.

Comment: I'm using c++98, nlohmann only support c++11

Comment: @epiphany have you considered rapidjson?

Comment: I am thinking of something like creating a string with both the concat values and then cast it to a char array, can I do that?

Comment: Unless you're working on a legacy code base, there's no good reason not to target at least C++11 these days.

Comment: unfortunately I am

Comment: So something like this?  int id = 10;
 std::string name = "joe";
 std::string json = "{\"id\":" + std::to_string(id) + ", \"name\":\"" + name + "\"}";´

Comment: Yes, but I am having problem at how to convert the string to a char array

Comment: you can get inspiration from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121378/json-cpp-how-to-initialize-from-string-and-get-string-value you can find also a direct link and sample here http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/old.html

Comment: _Yes, but I am having problem at how to convert the string to a char array_ ??? [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) (and may be `std::string::size()`) should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
char * toJSON(int const id, std::string const& name)
{
    std::string json = "{\"id\":" + std::to_string(id) + ", \"name\":\"" + name + "\"}";

    char * arr = new char[json.length() + 1 /* terminating 0 */];

    strcpy_s(arr, json.length() + 1, json.c_str());

    return arr;
}
```

Don't forget to delete the array after you are done using it.