# How to create a json object from scratch in c++ using picojson.h

Tags: c++, json, serialization

Trying to serialize a class I have into a json string. Of course I can just write the strings manually, but I was hoping to utilize a the **picojson** library.

What I am trying to achieve is, given this class A

```
class A {
  public:
    int field1;
    string field2;
}

A a;
a.field1 = 1;
a.field2 = "example";
```

I want to convert this class instance "a" into a picojson object and then call picojson::serialize() to get the json string.

```
{"field1": 1, "field2": "example"}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121378/json-cpp-how-to-initialize-from-string-and-get-string-value) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well completely of the top of my head, and just by looking at the header file, it seems you need something like this

```
using namespace picojson;

object o;
o["field1"] = value(static_cast<double>(a.field1));
o["field2"] = value(a.field2);
std::cout << value(o);
```

or (what you actually asked for)

```
std::string s = value(o).serialize();
```

Comment: Well I've now tested the above code, and made one small correction (added the static_cast), so you should be good to go.